# PowerShell Need to delete a NamedPipe - how?

Tags: powershell, named-pipes

I need a Named Pipe. This pipe could have been already defined by the same PowerShell-Script earlier, and I can find it by:

```
$pipeName = "testpipe"
$delPipe = [System.IO.Directory]::GetFiles("\\.\pipe\") | where { $_ -match $pipeName }
```

The simple

```
 Remove-Item $delPipe
```

fails :(
What do I have to do to delete / cancel this pipe?
Can I found out 'what is locking' this pipe by e.g. Lockhunter?

Thanks in advance,
Gooly

PS for others to give them an idea
I found a solution so that a free pipe is chosen and time will delete the previously used pipes:

```
 $BaseName = "testpipe"
 $n = 0;
 do {
     $n++
     $pipeName = "$BaseName$n"
     $usedPipe = [System.IO.Directory]::GetFiles("\\.\pipe\") | where { $_ -match $pipeName }
 } while ( $usedPipe.Length -gt 5 )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Named pipes are not deleted by user code. As per the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365150(v=vs.85).aspx):

> An instance of a named pipe is always deleted when the last handle to
>   the instance of the named pipe is closed.

The [topic is discussed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17423689/503046) from C# side too, which is quite close a match as Powershell leverages .Net too.